# Angular CSS View to be applied on children

Tags: css, angular

I'm learning Angular from a  ReactJS and JSVanilla background. I'm trying to understand how Angular build its views and how can we work with  them.

My question is: What is the best way (or available options) to make parent css reflect / constraint child css on Angular?

Example, using JSVanilla:

```
<section class="parent">
    <section class="child">
         <section class="grandchild">
         </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

```css
.parent{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 800px;
}

.child{
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
}

.grandchild{
    height: 30%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

In this case, each section would be a component by itself.

Comment: you can use [`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), or [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

Comment: gonna take a look on that, see if works well enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, studying for a few, I've come up with a nice solution which involves the `:host` selector.

In angular, after all the components in a module being rendered, we get the following *pseudo-tree*:

```html
<app-parent>
    <section class="parent">

        <app-child>
             <section class="child">

                 <app-grandchild>
                     <section class="grandchild">
                     </section>
                 </app-grandchild>

             </section>
        </app-child>

    </section>
</app-parent>
```

As we can see, the constraints of the child is being marked by the `<app-tag/>`, which dictates how the children will be rendered.

In terms of size, but not all attributes, the best option for me was to use the `:host selector`, which selects the `<app-tag/>`. In the css, will look like this:

```css
:host{
    height:80%;
    width: 90%;
}

.child{
     /* child styles here */ 
}
```

And this resolved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about View Encapsulation concept in Angular.
There are 3 types of View encapsulation.

1. ViewEncapsulation.None
2. ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
3. ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

You can place encapsulation in @Component decorator as shown in the below code snippet

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shadow-dom-encapsulation',
  template: `
    <h2>ShadowDom</h2>
    <div class="shadow-message">Shadow DOM encapsulation</div>
    <app-emulated-encapsulation></app-emulated-encapsulation>
    <app-no-encapsulation></app-no-encapsulation>
  `,
  styles: ['h2, .shadow-message { color: blue; }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
```

Please read the below article, Hope it helps!!
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/templates-styles-view-encapsulation/